# Spring Boot and Kafka upgrade broke my tests

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

I have updated the libraries of one project, in particular, I've updated Spring Boot, from version 2.2.6 to 2.3.2.

As mentioned in [the migration documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#dependency-upgrades), this would also mean a change in my Kafka dependencies, going up to Spring Kafka and Kafka 2.5

However, since this change, some of my tests 'randomly' fail, as in, when I execute all of my tests, I encounter this failure in some of them (but not always in the same tests):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: More than one record for topic found
```

Coming from this particular line:

```java
KafkaTestUtils.getSingleRecord(consumer, topicConfiguration.getTopic(event))
```

There is no mention in the documentation as to why this is happening, and no other log error message throwing light as to why this is happening. As I haven't changed the logic of my application, am I missing something with the migration?

If I try something like this:

```
KafkaTestUtils.getRecords(consumer)
    .records(topicConfiguration.getTopic(event)).map { it }[0]
```

To get only the first one, tests that worked previously would fail with an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` due to the index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [test documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/6b0f74c51f7bf3d91a35f6c23478bd06bda9c7df/src/reference/asciidoc/testing.adoc) of the Spring Kafka library, starting with version 2.5 they changed the way they configure the consumers. This is the exact quote:

> Starting with version 2.5, the `consumerProps` method sets the `ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG` to `earliest`. This is because, in most cases, you want the consumer to consume any messages sent in a test case. The `ConsumerConfig` default is `latest` which means that messages already sent by a test, before the consumer starts, will not receive those records. To revert to the previous behavior, set the property to `latest` after calling the method.

It could be very likely the reason of the described test errors.

Comment: Nice! I am happy to hear that the answer was helpful.